# How can I use Json.reads to deserialize JSON into a case class with optional constructor parameters

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following case class and JSON

```
case class Profile(name: String, `type`: String, value: String, sort: Long = 0)

val json_string = """[
  {"name": "Birthday", "type": "DateTime", "value": "12/25/1990"},
  {"name": "Fullname", "type": "String", "value": "Birthday Boy"}
]"""
```

The following call:

```
val profiles = Json.parse(json_string).as[Seq[Profile]]
```

Results in the exception:

```
JsResultException(errors:List(((0)/sort,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray()))), ((1)/sort,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))
```

If I add the a `sort` key to my JSON string the deserialization works as expected.  Why doesn't the default value for `sort` in the case class "kick in" and allow the deserialization?

I'm using [JsMacroInception](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception) to define the reads/writes

```
   val implicit profileReader = Json[Profile].reads
   val implicit profileWriter = Json[Profile].writes
```

Can I do something with the reader to support the optional constructor parameter?

Comment: In Spray-json you would make the type an Option, e.g. Option[Long].

Comment: I could make it an option, but I'd prefer to have a default value if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON reads macro won't take default constructor values into account when generating `Reads[Profile]`. So if you want to still use the macro, your only choice is to make `sort` an `Option[Long]`. If you want to provide a default value, then I suggest you go with JSON combinators:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val reads: Reads[Profile] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and 
    (__ \ "type").read[String] and 
    (__ \ "value").read[String] and 
    (__ \ "sort").read[Long].orElse(Reads.pure(0L))
)(Profile.apply _)
```

If `sort` isn't found within a JSON object, `orElse` will be applied, which in this case I use `Reads.pure` to provide a fixed default value.

Comment: Nice, I was dancing around `orElse` but I couldn't quite figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You need  to make sort an Option but then null or non included value would be none . If that does not work you would then have to write your own reads to set default value in case of null / missing sort

Comment: Its not clear to me how to make my own reads for this.  Do you have any ideas?